# How spotify RESTful webservices is used in Java?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, spotify

Though my question seems more generic I only want to know that how can I use the spotify REST webservice in java. A link for the tutorial will also be helpful.
The tutorial from the spotify website didn't help.

Comment: Their website has sections dedicated to your exact question - https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/code-examples/ and https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/ I'd suggest closing the question as a simple Google search will provide all the resources you'll need, and providing links as answers isn't really a suitable response - what if links move?

Comment: Just as every REST service. REST is a standard and there is a ton of libraries offering support for REST.

You can try Spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Answer (score 0):

If the official tutorial didn't help, I recommend trying the Java wrapper here: https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-java

The README provides several useful examples for different use cases and the helper functions it provides should do most of the leg work for you.